# How can I get the selected items for adding an order in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have three entities user, item, order. ORDER entity has ManyToMany association with item and ManyToOne with user.

**1.Item Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class Item {
Integer id;
String name;
String category;

@ManyToMany
Order order;

}
```

**2.User Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class user {
Integer id;
String username;
String email;

@OneToMany
Order order;

}
```

**3.order Entity**

```java
@Entity
public class order {
Integer id;
Integer price;
Integer quantity;
String address;
Integer p_number;

@ManyToOne
Use user;

@ManyToMany
Item item;

}
```

I've problem with adding an order, I don't know how to get selected items in **orderService** class for addOrder method?

**OrderServiceImpl.java**

```java
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    OrderRepo orderRepo;

    public Order addOrder (Order order) {
        return orderRepo.save(order);
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't fields annotated with ManyToMany and OneToMany be collections?

Answer (score 0):

In mapping , the fields representing many side have to be either list or set

In user entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
List<Order> orders;
```

In item entity

```
@ManyToMany
List<Order> orders;
```

In order entity

```
@ManyToOne
Use user;

@ManyToMany
List<Item> items;
```